# How to control files with the same name key in multipart/form-data received via HTTP POST in PHP

Tags: php, multipartform-data, multiple-file-upload

[image: packet capture img]

I would like to process a file with the same name key as in the picture above in PHP. How should I process it?
The request API cannot be modified, so the name key cannot be processed as an array.
So, the PHP receiving side needs a way to process multiple files with the same name key without a name array.
Or is it possible to process multiple files by forcibly arranging the name key on the PHP receiving side?

```
$file_info = print_r($_FILES[files]);
```

When checking the value of file name with the code above, only one file can be processed.

Comment: PHP can't handle repeated keys unless they have a `[]` suffix. AFAIK, there is no work around other than implementing a proxy to rewrite the request body. See https://www.php.net/manual/features.file-upload.multiple.php